# Reading multiple excel files from a certain path (with certain sheets names) into a single pandas data frame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

How can I read only sheets '2g','3g','4g' from all the excel files exists in a certain path and write them to three different data frames.
All 2g sheets should be stored in a pandas data frame called (2g)
All 3g sheets should be stored in a pandas data frame called (3g)
All 4g sheets should be stored in a pandas data frame called (4g)
following the screenshot of the excel files :
[image]

and the sheets I want to read from each excel files as in the screen below :

[image]

Comment: Have you checked pandas docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html? Should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: but how can I loop on all the excel files inside this path and take a certain sheet name each time I loop, and then add what I read to concatenate with pandas DF 2g for example ? Thanks for helping

Comment: I wrote a code do this before, but only on one excel file, here below what I wrote :import pandas as pd
NUR = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jalal.hasain\Desktop\Copy of NUR Data 20-12.xlsx', 
                   sheet_name=['2G','3G','4G','Rank'])twoG=NUR.get('2G')
threeG=NUR.get('3G')
fourG=NUR.get('4G')

Comment: Put sheets into list variable and do a for loop. Then concat the data as your require (add rows or columns to existing dfs or create totally new ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `read_excel` with multiple sheet names:

```
import pandas as pd

data2g = []
data3g = []
data4g = []

for xlsx in pathlib.Path('mobile').glob('*.xlsx'):
    df2g, df3g, df4g = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name=['2G', '3G', '4G']).values()
    data2g.append(df2g)
    data3g.append(df3g)
    data4g.append(df4g)

df2g = pd.concat(data2g, ignore_index=True)
df3g = pd.concat(data3g, ignore_index=True)
df4g = pd.concat(data4g, ignore_index=True)
```

As you can see, you can improve readability using loops:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
for xlsx in pathlib.Path('mobile').glob('*.xlsx'):
    out = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name=['2G', '3G', '4G'])
    for k, v in out.items():
        data[k].append(v)
df2g, df3g, df4g = [pd.concat(data[k], ignore_index=True) for k in data]
```

Comment: Does it what you expect?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! appreciated. May I just have one more Question, when I put the path I did this : for xlsx in pathlib.Path('C:\Users\jalal.hasain\Desktop\Dec NUR').glob('*.xlsx'): , but it is giving : SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
I think I did something wrong with adding the path. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use / and not \ or prefix your path by r'...' to enable raw strings.

Comment: `'C:/Users/jalal.hasain/Desktop/Dec NUR')` or `r'C:\Users\jalal.hasain\Desktop\Dec NUR'`

Comment: I was trying on jupyter notebook, it is not giving any error, but the cell on the left gives like this: In [*], I don't know why

Comment: Process is running :-). Each file is about 3mb. How many files do you have?

Comment: I wrote this : import pandas as pd
import pathlib

data2g = []
data3g = []
data4g = []

for xlsx in pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\jalal.hasain\Desktop\Dec NUR').glob('*.xlsx'):
    df2g, df3g, df4g = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name=['2G', '3G', '4G']).values()
    data2g.append(df2g)
    data3g.append(df3g)
    data4g.append(df4g)

df2g = pd.concat(data2g, ignore_index=True)
df3g = pd.concat(data3g, ignore_index=True)
df4g = pd.concat(data4g, ignore_index=True)

df2g.to_excel("2g_file.xlsx") 
df3g.to_excel("3g_file.xlsx") 
df4g.to_excel("4g_file.xlsx")

Comment: OOh I have more than 30 files, thats gonna take sometime

Comment: Thanks you very much for helping, I think its gonna take sometime, I will tell you when it's done, thanks again